# PHP include file in entire directory

Tags: php, php-include

I've been working on some projects in which we have configuration files, and other functions that are used on multiple pages to be included through php as an external file. I've been looking into a way to do something similar to that, but instead of having to include it in every single file, have it included on every file in a directory.

Is this possible at all? I'm trying to use it for some very simple things such as queries, or inclusions, or error reporting, so i dont have to have that include line on each page.

(side note: I know its lazy, and no, its not a needed thing... at this point, its more of curiosity than application)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done some research or tried something to accomplish your goal?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: *"I know its lazy"* - Hey, "you" said it, we didn't.

Comment: There's [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file). But that's more of a workaround really.

Comment: If your project uses classes, you might look into [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: Yeah, i've looked at a few things, but almost everything points back to just manually including the files you need. Like i said, i was just more curious if it was possible to do something like add a function to act as shorthand for a longer more complicated function.

for one of my projects, its the mysqli_query() or die(mysqli_error()); --its not hard to type out during tests, but for testing stuff, i'd like to be able to just do a shorthand like xQRY(); , and have it do what its supposed to. Thinking along those lines, i was curious if you could essentially add 'custom ' global functions.

Comment: auto_prepend_file may be the closest thing to the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is have a file called includer.php. That file contains something like:

```
<?php

include_once("pageBuilder.php");
include_once("helperFunctions.php");

?>
```

Then in individual files I have this at the top:

```
<?php

include_once("includer.php");
include_once("fileOnlyThisPageNeeds.php");

?>
```

This can be improved in a number of ways, but that's the general idea.

That way you can include any file in `includer.php` and it will be included in all the pages you need.

**EDIT:**

I don't recommend forcing all pages to include a file - If you decide you don't want one page to have the file included later on, you'll have to go back and use some other method.

It's very little work to add that one line. It will save you time later.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing this would be to route everything to one entry point using htaccess, e.g:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.+$ /index.php [L]
```

In your index.php file you can then include the relevant files you mention.

And then, depending on how your application is structured, you can then just take the request URI and parse it as normal.

If you take requests to php files, it's as simple as then including the relevant file. If your application is bootstrapped or has another master application file, then include that, etc.

I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader ;)